# InAppBrowser in phonegap 2.3.0

Tags: android, cordova, childbrowser

In my android project i am using Phonegap 2.2.0 with child browser.

i went through Phonegap 2.3.0 at Phonegap documentation, i got attracted when i saw inAppBrowser so,i thought by using phonegap 2.3.0 i can avoid child browser plugin and i tried to use.

My question is, **i am using child browser's onLocationChange method, i need something similar in inAppBrowser**, but i gone through full inAppBrowser documentation at phonegap.

there is only three events in inAppBrowser ([Phonegap 2.3.0 documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser))

1. loadstart - event fired when the InAppBrowser starts to load a URL
2. loadstop - event fired when the InAppBrowser finished loading a URL
3. exit - event fired when the InAppBrowser window is closed

I just tried 1&2 events to see how they are working, as i was expected these two events are not match for child browser's onLocationChange method.

is there any solution ? or i have stick with child browser ?

Comment: Wouldn't loadstart work more or less the same as locationChange?

Comment: Um, loadstart fires exactly the same as location change. Not sure what your problem actually is.

Comment: not exactly @SimonMacDonald.. i tried..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me `loadstop` worked by adding following lines,

```
iabrowser = window.open(url, target, op);
iabrowser.addEventListener('loadstop', locChanged);
```

Make sure you initialize `iabrowser` properly.